# How to create auto-reply loop rule in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, email-filter, infinite-loop, auto-reply

My company is still using Outlook 2003. For the second day in a row we have 60,000+ email auto replies in our inbox.

Our IT department aren't able to figure out how to stem the tide so my question is this:

How do I create a 'custom rule' to ensure only a set number of auto replies are sent to the same email address within a set time frame? Say 5 replies only within an hour.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the auto reply feature rather than inbox rules to reply.

The auto reply feature automatically only allows one reply per person, per subject within a set time and basically has detection to cut out looping.